# Remove GDM with Lightm installed

Tags: 17.10, lightdm, gdm

I' m using ubuntu 17.10 which comes preinstalled with GDM.
However though i dont like GDM i installed LightDM.

My question is now can i remove GDM without any issues?

br.

Answer (score 2):

Don't remove gdm3 because if you ever have a problem with lightdm you can revert back to the default gdm3 login display manager. You can switch back and forth from gdm3 to lightdm by running this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

This will bring up a new screen allowing you to select either gdm3 or lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select either gdm3 or lightdm, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then run `sudo reboot` to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`? It should open up a screen where you can set lightdm as default.

Also you can do `sudo apt purge gdm` to uninstall gdm if you want.